# Most efficient way to check that string variable is a single alphanumeric character

Tags: javascript

I could do it with regex (something like `myString.match(/^[A-Za-z0-9]$/)`) but it seems like an overkill.

What would be more effective performance-wise?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the length property and the charCodeAt( 0 ) function to check the range of the ASCII value...

Answer (score 1):

Well obviously, the most efficient is an indexed lookup into an array (pre-configured with appropriate boolean results). This is a very bad approach, in general, however. (Because it's non-standard and almost certainly not neccessary).

Comment: Why regexp is an bad approach? I was thinking that would make the code more readable and easy to change the code when my criteria changes.. And why indexed lookup is better?

Comment: @Vijay: It's better because it costs no time (or, to put it in 'Big Oh' it's, O(1). Lookup (table lookup) is the fastest way to do anything. Regexp is not a bad approach (I didn't say that, I was saying *my* suggested approach is "bad" (though it's the fastests)). Regexp is definitely the best approach in your specific case. Slow as it may be, it's clear, and scalable to a change in requirements. My method isn't. (easily). And I doubt this particular area will be your bottleneck (and if it is, there may be a better way to solve it, in general).